# Android Instrumentation Test Case

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation, dex, dexclassloader

I would like to test an activity from an other apk, and this test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.html) because I will need to get the Activity and Instrumentation.

I try to use a DexClassLoader like this:

```
    public MainActivityTest() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    super((new DexClassLoader(
                "/data/app/my-application.apk", "/data/app/my-application",null, MainActivityTest.class.getClassLoader())).loadClass("my-application.MainActivity")))}
```

But I get as result an Exception: `optimizedDirectory not readable/writable: /data/data/valentin.myapplication2`

Is there a solution to do it?

I need the activity because i use this after: `activity.getWindow().getDecorView()`

FYI:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    mActivity = getActivity();
}

@Test
public void testRecorder(){

   new ActivityListener(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),mActivity,12).start();
    while(true){
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use Espresso. [Look here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/BasicSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/BasicSample/ChangeTextBehaviorTest.java) there is an example. which already features an test with an acitivty. Hope this helps you. Otherwise I would say the path looks suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

You should never hardcode paths like that in your code. First off, /data/app is the wrong path - that is where the apk itself lives and only the system can write there. You can use [getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir()) to get the path to your applications data directory, which you can write to.

When using DexClassLoader, you have to provide a path that is writable, because the system will optimize the dex file and write the optimized version to the location you specify.

```
public Class getActivityClass(Context ctx)
        throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ApplicationInfo pi = ctx.getPackageManager()
    .getApplicationInfo("my.application", 0);
    String apkPath = pi.sourceDir;

    DexClassLoader loader = new DexClassLoader(apkPath,
            ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), null,
            this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    return loader.loadClass("my-application.MainActivity");
}
```